# What is the term for a request that redraws the whole web page?

Tags: html, ajax, terminology

I feel like I'm always stumbling over the language used to distinguish between an AJAX request and a standard web request (one that redraws the whole page using HTML returned from the server).  In other words, what's the term for the **opposite** of an AJAX request?

Comment: I don't think there is any "standard" English definition used to describe this, but I would call it HTTP Request or simply page load

Comment: I'd refer to it as a page request, but I'm uncertain if that's standard terminology, so +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say Full Postback vs. Asynchronous / Partial postback. But I'm sure there are tons of technically incorrect issues with that...

Comment: Seems there's no definitive answer here, but I like this over "full page refresh" because I think of a refresh as not processing any new POST or GET data before the redraw.

Answer (score 1):

On the level of the request, there is no difference. It's all HTTP GETs or POSTS. The difference is in the effect. I might call it a page load vs. a page update.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the term "**full page refresh**", although it can be slightly ambiguous since you can use AJAX to load a new page and replace the current page with it (like mobile jQuery does). Still I think it's a decent enough term for common use.

Comment: "refresh" sounds odd here, but it's unclear whether the OP is specifically thinking of scenarios within a single page (as your definition would apply) or any kind of navigation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've heard it called refresh before, but I have no reference or anything. "Postback" would be more traditional I guess, if you come from the ASP.NET world, ymmv!

Answer (score 0):

In the ASP.NET world, you could differentiate between a "postback" and AJAX. Although that doesn't necessarily imply a full page refresh

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-postback-vs-ajax.html